# Run Workflow even when Item is checked out - SharePoint 2013 (Metalogix Migration)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, migration, metalogix

I am using Metalogix tool to migrate data from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013. The issue is that the documents get checked out in the destination. There is no way to resolve this, no settings work. 
  What I want is the Modified By name to not get changed. But since the documents are getting checked out, I need to check them back in and this results in a change in the modified by column. 
  I can save the modified by value in another column. This can be done using workflow(Wait till check out, save the value in a column, check in the document). This works when I manually add the document and check out manually. The workflow runs, modified by column value is stored in another column and document is checked in after that(through the workflow only). 
  But, when done through Migration, the workflow does not run at all(Because, workflow does not run on items that are checked out, but the same workflow works fine when I manually check out documents). Hence, the document is checked out and I am back to square one again.

Anyone has a way to - 1. Don't check out the documents in destination after migration. Or
2. Run workflow even when the document is checked out. or
3. Anyway to preserve the Modified by value and check in the document.

Comment: Shell scripting is not available

Comment: I'd ask Metalogix support for help - they'll know about these sorts of issues.